# Generating a list of supported devices by WURFL capabilities

Tags: java, mobile, wurfl

Is there an efficient way to programatically generate a list of supported devices based on a set of required capabilities using the [WURFL](http://wurfl.com) APIs?

For example I have two versions of an application; one that runs on Nokia Series60 version 2 handsets (Symbian 7/8) and a different version that runs on Nokia Series60 version 3 handsets (Symbian 9).  I need to get all such handset from the WURFL to present as on a 'supported handsets' page as well as check UAs of users who attempt to download so I can pass them the correct version of the application.

Conceptually I think I am looking for something like this:

```
return all devices that have capabilities :=
  device_os == Symbian OS  
  &&  nokia_series == 60 
  && (nokia_edition == 2 || nokia_edition == 3)
```

I am looking to do this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [new Java WURFL API](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava/) to load and trawl through the capabilities database.  It's pretty flexible that way, you should be able to implement your pseudo-code pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  We have looked into the new API, and while it offers some better ways then the old API it still seems like a hack, and it's not fast.  For now we are doing it and caching the result so it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers talked about how to use the Java WURFL API. However, to speed up the search at runtime, I'd recommend storing a hashmap or dictionary in memory mapping the user agent string (or a trimmed down version of the original string) to its corresponding device info.  The total amount of data should not be that big - merely on the order of megabytes.  Also, the WURFL data is fairly static, so one can preprocess the entire dataset offline to build the hashmap.  I usually preprocess and update the hashmap periodically, serialize the object, and load it during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an API for this task.  I've had to deal with this myself and ended up coding a public site to handle it: http://wurfl.ditherandbicker.com/

Since the base WURFL XML file is built for portability, a device's full capability matrix must be derived by reading from a variable number of "fall back devices".  Many other WURFL-based projects behave the same way.  In my experience you really need to translate the default, nested, data structure into a flat one if you hope to get any decent speed with your searches.  Of course at that point you lose the portability benefits.